# PDO perform 2 mysql selects in the same loop

Tags: php

quick question!
how do i perform 2 selects with PDO and run them through the same loop ? 
`$sql1 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM produkts");`
`$sql2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM buyers");`
`$sql1->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`
`$sql1->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`
`while($row = $stmt->fetch() && $row1 = $stmt1->fetch()){`
`Something to be displayed`
`}`
This obviously doesn't work, and i have no clue how to make it work.

how is this performed ??

Comment: Is there a common column between the two tables? You may be able to `JOIN` or `UNION` the data, but there needs to be similarities.

Comment: Yes, the produkt id is mentioned in the buyers tabel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming something like:

```
Buyers       Produkts
----------   ---------
buyerid    .-produktid
produktid-'  [...]
[...]
```

You can use:

```
SELECT       b.*, p.*
FROM         buyers b
  LEFT JOIN  produkts p
  ON         p.produktid = b.produktid
```

That will go through and query each `buyers` then for every `produktid` supplied and found in the `produkts` table, it will be joined in the result. You can also reverse it it bring buys in on products: For example:

```
SELECT       p.*, b.*
FROM         produkts p
  LEFT JOIN  buyers b
  ON         b.produktid = p.produktid
```

Which will bring in the `buyers` details based on a `produkts` match.

This is going by what you've told me, that both tables share a `produktid` column. I still don't know what you're after or know any more about the table schema, so if I'm off let me know (and provide more information).

Comment: To be clear your query will produce a slightly different result

Comment: Thanks i will look onto it, and make it match my query, thanks alot :)